# First fluid liquid animation- feedback!

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I have made my  first animation using fluids! It is a splash of water hitting a rotating caracter. The scene is quite simple, but there are issues I cannot fix. For instance the shape of the water just before it is hitting the caracter very 'shield' like. And after  the water has run off the caracter, the waterdrops on the plane is flickering  in the animation. I really would  appreceiate some feedback  on all possible improvements:) The animation is 20 sec, rendered on 256.
For animation, see link: https://vimeo.com/537149024

file: [image]

Comment: your link is not working

Comment: uups, it is working on my computer when I click the link in this post.Correct link:vimeo.com/537149024

Comment: can you provide blend file? for me it looks like the resolution is too low. Also the water material could look better. Maybe use some more water so you don't have these flickering "edge" effects

Comment: Absolutely, but since this is my first post here, I don't know how to add the file....

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/ follow the instructions

Comment: thanks! Sorry for  beeing  such a neewbie, but think the  file is linked in the post now

Comment: no problem - we all started once. But some people here forget this. And i think you did not read all the rules you have to follow here, right? ;) neither do i. But there are people here who think people first read 3h the rules you should follow here and they forgot what the sense of this is: help other people. My tips are in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommendations:

1. Start a complete new Blender file with just the default cube.
2. go to quick effects -> quick liquid
3. start the animation -> looks great, right?
4. so you should try to keep the settings there in your file and tweak only one effect at a time to see what happens if you do that. -> or watch tons of tutorial videos

Now to your file:

to improve it you can do...

1. decrease resolution to 64 or 128 when you are still changing things, if you render you increase this to 256 if you like, else it takes too long and your computer will slow down
2. for me it looks like you "wildly" changed some settings just to get better results - without knowing what happens. e.g.
   [image]

of course you can change these values (which i personally never did and i made nice looking water simulations without it), but if you increase it that hight, i just don't wanna know how long your render time for your simulation was...1 week? ;)

So put it down to the default values 4 and 1 ...and wow...your computer and your simulation is fast again

3. put on all border collisions -> else you got these weird results where just "some" water is on the floor which does not look realistic.

[image]

4. check liquid and don't change default settings

[image]

5. you got this: https://youtu.be/QAH1ljMFkEA
6. turn on spray, foam, bubbles

[image]

7. most important: Do the render in cycles. Only in cycles water looks really good and realistic. But change to cycles after you did all your settings because this also slows down your computer massively.

quick result of cycles render (bad resolution):
[image]

bit higher resolution (128)

[image]

Best recommendation: Don't use mantaflow.

Use Flip Fluids. I know -  you have to pay for it.
I know it is "kind of" advertising although i do not get anything from them and i don't have any relationship to the FlipFluid - addon creators.
It is just an amazing add-on which makes fluids look a lot better and - even more important - it is so much faster!!!

Here is a result of your simulation which i just did with a few clicks with FlipFluids....deleted your background, used a HDRI and ...you won't believe it ...rendered in EEVEE:

result:

[image]

aaaaand.....NOOOOOW....Cycles:

[image]

Remember: These are JUST the default settings of FlipFluids. I just assigned default materials (which are part of FlipFluids) and checked 2 checkmarks (so you can see foam + spray)

Comment: great-thanks again, trying it all out right now

Comment: you are welcome